# How to remove the text "Continued on next page", in longtblr?

Tags: page-breaking, text, longtblr, remove

How to remove the text "Continued on next page", in `longtblr`?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\usepackage[a4paper,margin=2mm]{geometry}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\DefTblrTemplate{firsthead, middlehead,lasthead}{default}{}
\begin{longtblr}[presep=-4pt,postsep=0pt]{colspec = {p{3cm}X},\textwidth,colsep=0pt}
First    & \lipsum[1-5]\\
Second   & \lipsum[1-5]\\
Third    & \lipsum[1-5]
\end{longtblr}

\end{document}
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: see https://topanswers.xyz/tex?q=6738

Comment: thanks a lot.... If you put it in an answer, I accept it..

Comment: Feel free to write one yourself.

Comment: Thanks @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz! To me, the latest one (i.e. ```\DefTblrTemplate{foot}{empty}{}
\SetTblrTemplate{foot}{empty}```) look similar to the previous solution, in the previous link (i.e. ```\DefTblrTemplate{contfoot-text}{normal}{}
\SetTblrTemplate{contfoot-text}{normal}```)